# Spyder Anaconda (Python 3.6) Module pptx not found error although module pptx is installed in Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pptx

Tags: python-3.x, powerpoint, spyder

I have a simple `Python` code to generate a PowerPoint slide.
...

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
```

...
Got this error message when I executed the code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx'
```

Comment: Please put some more love into how you present your question to others. Tip: code formatting + letting people know what you've tried so far to solve your problem.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [this guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to solve this problem.